# Mantener paneles ordenados del C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net

Quiero que por cada archivo de un carpeta, se cree un panel y vaya directo al contenedor de Paneles ( esto ya esta hecho )  pero el problema esque cada uno de esos paneles tenga su espacio reservado o que se comporten de manera similar al `Position: relative;` de CSS.

[image: AFAF]

Ese es el codigo

Y así es como se ve cuando el `foreach` hace su trabajo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En realidad los dos paneles estan en el mismo lugar, quisiera saber como hacer que cada uno de ellos se orden.

Codigo

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Crear_Nota_Panel.Visible = !true;
            this.Contenedor_Paginas_GODS.Visible = !this.Contenedor_Paginas_GODS.Visible;
            if(this.Contenedor_Paginas_GODS.Visible == !false) { LabelDNK.Text = "Estas en \"Paginas\""; } else { LabelDNK.Text = Texto.Obtener("NDK"); }
            string PATH = string.Empty;
            this.Contenedor.Controls.Clear();
            if (Directory.Exists(@"C:\notas\"))
            {
                PATH = @"C:\notas\";
                DirectoryInfo Directorio = new DirectoryInfo(PATH);
                int asgasg = Directorio.GetFiles().Length;
                Console.WriteLine(asgasg);
                foreach (var ObjetosPATH in Directorio.GetFiles())
                {
                    Panel ItemPATH = new Panel();
                    ItemPATH.Parent = this.Contenedor;
                    ItemPATH.Height = Contenedor.Height / 3;
                    ItemPATH.Width = Contenedor.Width;
                    ItemPATH.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("La carpeta contenedora de las paginas no existe aun. Trata de guardar una nota para crearla");
            }
```

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon tu codigo como texto

Comment: Ya esta, ya edite la pregunta